# Best way to export and import content

Tags: data-export

We have a requirement to export the content and import into another org.

We used file exporter to export the content, but getting the below error:
"A duplicate file name exists , or the file cannot be found"

all the files are exported but the size is 0.

Can anyone please suggest a better way to export the content and import it to another org.

Comment: I'm not sure what the file exporter is. Do you have a link to it?
That said, the [Force.com Data Loader](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Data_Loader) is a capable tool for exporting your data as CSVs and then importing it into another Org.

Comment: Below is the link for the file exporter app:  Thanks for comments; but what is the bext app/tool to export contents & attachments https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003Iz0jEAC